# How do I get the value of a current user's custom field?

Tags: php, functions, custom-field, hooks

I'm trying to display the current logged in user's info in a particular page i'm working on, and i've managed to display some of the user's info. But I decided to add a custom field to the user's profile such as "Agent Department", "Agent Contact" using this code:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="agentdept"><?php _e("Agent Department"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="agentdept" id="agentdept" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'agentdept', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e("Enter Agent Department"); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="agentmobile"><?php _e("Agent Mobile"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="agentmobile" id="agentmobile" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'agentmobile', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e("Enter Agent Mobile."); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'agentdept', $_POST['agentdept'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'agentmobile', $_POST['agentmobile'] );
}
```

My question is, how do I get the value of these custom fields and display it on my front end? I really would appreciate the help. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the frontend and you should be able to adjust it to display whatever field you've added.

```
$user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "<br>";
echo 'User roles: ' . implode(', ', $user_info->roles) . "<br>";
echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "<br>";
echo 'User Agent Department: ' . $user_info->agentdept . "<br>";
echo 'User Agent Mobile: ' . $user_info->agentmobile . "<br>";
```

Comment: You are absolutely wonderful! Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome - Glad to help!